# If a crime victim is a member of the US military, must local law enforcement defer jurisdiction to the military?

Tags: criminal-law, military

I was watching a cop show the other day, and city police were at the scene of a one-victim crime. It was determined that the victim was a service member. The lead detective then muttered, "which means it's a military crime"

Which makes me wonder - Suppose Serviceman Bob is the victim of a murder off base, Further suppose that this is one of those cases that the military can investigate. Question is, can the military seize control over the investigation, or are they required to allow the local police to deal with the case as the local PD sees fit?

Comment: Probably the basis for this is that murdering military personnel (or any federal officer) is a federal crime. The murderer will have violated both state and federal law. That presumably lets the feds take the investigation out of the hands of the local cops. How the feds decide which federal agency has jurisdiction, I do not know.